# In Perl 6, is there a way to get the Pod declarator block that is attached to a specific multi sub candidate?

Tags: raku, code-documentation

Perl 6 has a cool feature which allows one to get any [Pod declarator block](https://docs.perl6.org/language/pod#Declarator_blocks) that is attached to a subroutine (or class, role, etc.), using the [`WHY` method](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/WHY):

```
#|(Some enlightening words about myfunc.)
sub myfunc (Int $i) { say "You provided an integer: $i"; };
#=(Some more words about myfunc.)

say &myfunc.WHY;
```

This displays:

```
Some enlightening words about myfunc.
Some more words about myfunc.
```

Unfortunately, when one has multiple candidates for a subroutine, one can't just invoke `.WHY` on the subroutine name:

```
#|(myfunc accepts an integer.)
multi myfunc (Int $i) { say "You provided an integer $i"; };
#|(myfunc accepts a string.)
multi myfunc (Str $s) { say "You provided a string $s"; };

say &myfunc.WHY;
```

The result:

```
No documentation available for type 'Sub'.
Perhaps it can be found at https://docs.perl6.org/type/Sub
```

Is there a way to get the Pod declarator block that is attached to a specific multi sub candidate?  Is there a way to do so for all a subroutine's candidates?

Comment: You are calling the `.WHY` on the implicitly created `proto` sub.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get all documentation via [candidates](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/candidates):

```
&myfunc.candidates>>.WHY
```

Get documentation of narrowest matching candidate via [cando](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/cando):

```
&myfunc.cando(\(42)).first.WHY
```

Comment: .oO ( What if `.WHY` called on a proto, after displaying its own doc if any, automatically called `.candidates>>.WHY`? )

Comment: @raiph Definitely sounds DWIM. At least I know I expected `.WHY` to work in this case ...

Answer (score 8):

You look up the multi with `candidates` or `cando`.

When initially posted I couldn't find a canned method for looking up a multi sub by signature but [Christoph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48015/christoph) remedied that.

```
#| Initiate a specified spell normally
multi sub cast(Str $spell) {
  say "casting spell $spell";
}
#= (do not use for class 7 spells)

#| Cast a heavy rock etc in irritation
multi sub cast(Str $heavy-item, Int $n) {
  say "chucking $n heavy $heavy-item";
}

say "doc for cast spell";
say &cast.candidates[0].WHY;

say "doc for throwing rocks";
say &cast.candidates[1].WHY;

say "find doc for throwing things";
for &cast.candidates {
    if .signature ~~ :( Str, Int ) {
        say .WHY;
    }
}

# more advanced
say &cast.cando(\(Str, Int))>>.WHY; # thanks to Christoph
&cast.candidates.first: { .signature ~~ :(Str, Int) } andthen .WHY.say;
```

OUTPUT:

```
doc for cast spell
Initiate a specified spell normally
(do not use for class 7 spells)
doc for throwing rocks
Cast a heavy rock etc in irritation
find doc for throwing things
Cast a heavy rock etc in irritation
... repeated for variants ...
```

Comment: you could write your last example more compactly by using something like `&cast.cando(\(Str, Int))>>.WHY`

Answer (score 4):

This is a little indirect, but ...

You can store each `multi myfunc` in a variable and call `WHY` on that variable, yet still call `myfunc` as before:

```
#!/bin/env perl6

#|(myfunc accepts an integer.)
my $func_int = multi myfunc (Int $i) { say "You provided an integer $i"; }
#=(More about Int version of myfunc)

#|(myfunc accepts a string.)
my $func_string = multi myfunc (Str $s) { say "You provided a string $s"; }
#=(More about Str version of myfunc)

myfunc(10);        # myfunc works as normal
say $func_int.WHY; # show POD declarator block

say ''; # Blank line to separate output into two groups

myfunc("bar"); 
say $func_string.WHY;
```

Resulting in this output:

> ```
> You provided an integer 10
> myfunc accepts an integer.
> More about Int version of myfunc
>
> You provided a string bar
> myfunc accepts a string.
> More about Str version of myfunc
> ```

This is using Rakudo Star 2018.01 on CentOS 6.7.

Answer (score 4):

This does not really answer your question, but tries to explain why using `WHY` on a `multi` does not work; it's mainly because it points to the `proto` of the `multi`

```
#|(my-multi-func accepts either an integer or a string)
proto my-multi-func (|) {*}

#|(myfunc accepts an integer.)
multi my-multi-func (Int $i) { say "You provided an integer $i"; };
#|(myfunc accepts a string.)
multi my-multi-func (Str $s) { say "You provided a string $s"; };

say "my-multi-func is a {&my-multi-func.perl} and does {&my-multi-func.WHY}";
```

I attach the `{&my-multi-func.perl}` here because that is what gave me the hint. If you don't define a `proto`, it returns

`` my-multi-func is a sub my-multi-func (;; Mu | is raw) { #`(Sub|59650976) ... } ``

, which is none of the defined `multi`s, ergo the `proto`. Of course if you want to access those particular definitions of the candidates, @Christopher Bottoms answer is just perfect.